# ghc stalling at "Deleting temp dirs"

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm working on a simple Haskell project, which has compiled fine thus far. A friend committed some changes via subversion to test something out, and now ghc stalls at the linking stage. I checked the verbose option and it seems to be hanging on "Deleting temp dirs" after linking. Even after reverting my friend's changes this slowdown is still occurring. The complete trace is:

```
 Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 8.6.5, stage 2 booted by GHC version 8.6.3
Using binary package database: /Users/maincomp/.ghcup/ghc/8.6.5/lib/ghc-8.6.5/package.conf.d/package.cache
package flags []
loading package database /Users/maincomp/.ghcup/ghc/8.6.5/lib/ghc-8.6.5/package.conf.d
wired-in package ghc-prim mapped to ghc-prim-0.5.3
wired-in package integer-gmp mapped to integer-gmp-1.0.2.0
wired-in package base mapped to base-4.12.0.0
wired-in package rts mapped to rts
wired-in package template-haskell mapped to template-haskell-2.14.0.0
wired-in package ghc mapped to ghc-8.6.5
package flags []
loading package database /Users/maincomp/.ghcup/ghc/8.6.5/lib/ghc-8.6.5/package.conf.d
wired-in package ghc-prim mapped to ghc-prim-0.5.3
wired-in package integer-gmp mapped to integer-gmp-1.0.2.0
wired-in package base mapped to base-4.12.0.0
wired-in package rts mapped to rts-1.0
wired-in package template-haskell mapped to template-haskell-2.14.0.0
wired-in package ghc mapped to ghc-8.6.5
*** Chasing dependencies:
Chasing modules from: *Test/CalcTests.hs
!!! Chasing dependencies: finished in 1.46 milliseconds, allocated 0.722 megabytes
Stable obj: [ESf6z :-> Src.Calc, ESf6D :-> Main]
Stable BCO: []
Ready for upsweep
  [NONREC
      ModSummary {
         ms_hs_date = 2020-09-29 22:32:36.870126817 UTC
         ms_mod = Src.Calc,
         ms_textual_imps = [(Nothing, Prelude)]
         ms_srcimps = []
      },
   NONREC
      ModSummary {
         ms_hs_date = 2020-09-29 22:33:01.447304406 UTC
         ms_mod = Main,
         ms_textual_imps = [(Nothing, Prelude), (Nothing, System.IO),
                            (Nothing, System.Exit), (Nothing, Src.Calc)]
         ms_srcimps = []
      }]
*** Deleting temp files:
Deleting: 
compile: input file ./Src/Calc.hs
*** Checking old interface for Src.Calc (use -ddump-hi-diffs for more details):
[1 of 2] Skipping  Src.Calc    ( Src/Calc.hs, Src/Calc.o )
*** Deleting temp files:
Deleting: 
compile: input file Test/CalcTests.hs
*** Checking old interface for Main (use -ddump-hi-diffs for more details):
[2 of 2] Skipping  Main             ( Test/CalcTests.hs, Test/CalcTests.o )
Upsweep completely successful.
*** Deleting temp files:
Deleting: 
link: linkables are ...
LinkableM (2020-09-29 22:39:10.279253082 UTC) Src.Calc
   [DotO ./Src/Calc.o]
LinkableM (2020-09-29 22:39:12.122642619 UTC) Main
   [DotO Test/CalcTests.o]
Test/CalcTests is up to date, linking not required.
*** Deleting temp files:
Deleting: 
*** Deleting temp dirs:
Deleting:
```

Any ghc gurus with insight into this?

Comment: Try clearing your cache/temp dir/reboot the machine to delete `/tmp`.